# custom module subpanel

Tags: sugarcrm

So I have two custom modules. they are related one-to-many.
Module A vardef has:`'lm_contacts' =>

```
array(
  'name' => 'lm_contacts',
  'type' => 'link',
  'relationship' => 'lm_contacts_relation',
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'vname' => 'LBL_LEADS',
),

'relationships' => 
array (
        'lm_contacts_relation' => 
        array (
            'lhs_module' => 'LM_LM_Objektas',
            'lhs_table' => 'lm_lm_objektas',
            'lhs_key' => 'id',
            'rhs_module' => 'LM_LM_contact_person',
            'rhs_table' => 'lm_lm_contact_person',
            'rhs_key' => 'lm_object ',
            'relationship_type' => 'one-to-many',
          ),
      ),
```

and module a has subpaneldef:

```
$layout_defs['LM_LM_Objektas'] = array(
// list of what Subpanels to show in the DetailView
    'subpanel_setup' => 
    array(
        'lm_contacts' => 
        array(
            'order' => 10,
            'module' => 'LM_LM_contact_person',
            'subpanel_name' => 'default',
            'sort_order' => 'asc',
            //'sort_by' => 'id',
            'title_key' => 'LBL_CONTACT_SUBPANEL_TITLE',
            'get_subpanel_data' => 'lm_contacts',
            'add_subpanel_data' => 'lm_contacts_id',
            'top_buttons' => 
            array (
                0 => 
                array (
                    'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
                ),
                1 => 
                array (
                    'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
                    'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
                    'popup_module' => 'LM_LM_contact_person',
                ),
            ),
        ),
),
);
```

Now module a: lm_objectas does display subpanel corectly, but when i try to add new reqord to lm_contacts module trough subpanel quick create button, record does create, but no realation data of field " 'rhs_key' => 'lm_object' " is created. so naturaly no new record on subpanle does get displayed.
What I am missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: So if you go to the non-quick create of the other module, do you have the option of setting the relationship to the first module, and if so, do those show up in the subpanel of the first module?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but I can explain:

You are not doing anything wrong, this is a bug I discovered in Sugar....

The reason why the record created from the quick create is related to the active record you are on is because the quick create button has a hidden form with the id of the current record mapped to the field that the subpanel module uses for that relationship.  But when you create a custom module, the quick create assumes that the relate field will be "moduleA_moduleB_id", which it is for the stock modules in Sugar.  But when you create a custom module in Sugar, it truncates all relationship fields (in the Bean and in the database) so that they are not over 25 characters.

Long story short, the quick create code assumes that the field that links the two together will have the same convention as the stock module relationships, which is wrong.

The only way to avoid this without fixing the code (or waiting for Sugar's bug fix), is to make sure that your custom module has a name less than 10 characters, including the key that it puts on the front (so really it should be 5-6 characters tops).

I've updated the code in my own install of Sugar and have reported the bug.  It may be fixed in the next update.

I'd explain how to fix it in your stock instance, but I'm afraid that would only confuse matters more.  But let me know if you still need to fix this, and I'll post the actual code.

Comment: do you have a fix for this or is there a bug reported for this at http://bugs.sugarcrm.com?